Errors when using \includegraphics inside minipage
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,fancyhdr,url,hyperref,siunitx}
\usepackage[bottom=0in,headheight=12.70894pt]{geometry}
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.75in}
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{430pt}
\title{My document}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CH]{My document}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[CF]{\thepage}
\section{Some filler text}
\section{Some math problems}
\subsection{stuff}
\begin{minipage}{.55\textwidth}
Let the height of trapezium $ABEF$ be $h$, the height of trapezium $ABCD$ be $h_1$, and the height of trapezium $EFCD$ be $h_2$.
\[\text{We know that }\frac{h_1}{h}=\frac{AB}{EF}=\frac{1}{3}\]
Therefore, $2h_1=h_2$. \\
The area of trapezium $ABCD$ is:
\[\frac{(3+5)\times h_1}{2}=4h_1 \left(\unit{cm^2}\right)\]
Similarly, the area of trapezium $EFCD$ is:
\[\frac{(5+9)\times2h_1}{2}=14h_1 \left(\unit{cm^2}\right)\]
Therefore, the ratio between the area of trapezium $ABCD$ and the area of trapezium $EFCD$ is:
\[\frac{S_{ABCD}}{S_{EFCD}}=\frac{4h_1}{14h_1}=\frac{2}{7}\]
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[.4\textwidth]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{image.png}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}

Here, I get a total of 13 errors from
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image.png}
\end{minipage}

Here are the errors:
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.55 \includegraphics
                     [width=0.5\linewidth]{image.png}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
You have written a length, but have not specified the appropriate units (pt, mm, cm etc.). If you have not written a length, check that you have not witten a linebreak \\ followed by square brackets […] anywhere.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.55 \includegraphics
                     [width=0.5\linewidth]{image.png}
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.55 \includegraphics
                     [width=0.5\linewidth]{image.png}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

Use of ??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> ???  
                ! LaTeX Error: relax invalid in file name. Lost: .
l.55 \includegraphics
                     [width=0.5\linewidth]{image.png}
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

LaTeX Error: File `\relax ' not found.
The compiler cannot find the file you want to include. Make sure that you have uploaded the file and specified the file location correctly.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.55 \includegraphics
                     [width=0.5\linewidth]{image.png}
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   ]
l.55 \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]
                                          {image.png}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
You have written a length, but have not specified the appropriate units (pt, mm, cm etc.). If you have not written a length, check that you have not witten a linebreak \\ followed by square brackets […] anywhere.
<to be read again> 
                   ]
l.55 \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]
                                          {image.png}
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.56 \end{minipage}
                   
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

Use of ??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> ???  
                ! LaTeX Error: relax invalid in file name. Lost: .
l.56 \end{minipage}
                   
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

LaTeX Error: File `\relax ' not found.
The compiler cannot find the file you want to include. Make sure that you have uploaded the file and specified the file location correctly.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.56 \end{minipage}
                   
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

The weird thing is, it's totally normal in other documents when I insert a figure into a minipage. I'm using Overleaf as my editor here.

The second minipage should be
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}

Suggestions:

$ABCD$ should be $\mathit{ABCD}$ since the former typically represents the product of four variables. You could define a proper command such as
\newcommand\quadrilateral[1]{\mathit{#1}}

and use \quadrilateral{ABCD} etc. later on.
I think you should use a larger width in the optional argument of \includegraphics (like width=\linewidth)

